# What is the difference between url name and view name in reverse() in django?

Tags: python, django, reverse

when I was reviewing django doc, I saw *reverse()* in [urlresolvers](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/urlresolvers/), I saw this sentence at the beginning of it which is: *viewname can be a URL pattern name or the callable view object.*, I want to know what is the difference or differences between these two options? Or do they have any differences at all?

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a little technical but important difference based on MVT design pattern; When we want to use *reverse()* **in models.py**( usually with *get_absolute_url* ) the *viewname* argument should be urlname of view which is in *urls.py* in a string format like this: 'app_name:url_name'. In this case, using a view_name (which should be imported before) will result a **NameError**; But when we want to use *reverse()* in **views.py** we can use view_name as *viewname* argument.